# Running tests of a composer package in vendor directory

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I have a project I created with composer `create-project` command, but before running `composer install`, I added one more package to project `composer.json` file.
After installing the packages, I correctly have all the dependencies including the one newly added in the vendor directory. What I want now is to run the tests of the package that I manually added to composer.json. I tried the below, but doesn't seem to run the tests of the said package

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: Why do you want to run the unit tests for a third party package? I think the only way is to clone the project from github and run them into the package's project. Or maybe you could use a custom autoloader to get phpunit know where to find the classes.

Comment: @marcal I forked the package and forced composer to use my fork .now I want to run tests that added to my fork. But you're right I sh'd just run tests against original package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having a similar problem, we have separate private packages in vendor folder that needed to be tested. By default composer `autoload-dev` includes only root package as mentioned here https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#root-package

To include your forked package just add an entry in your root composer.json file under autoload-dev

```
"autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Company\\Package\\Tests\\": "vendor/package/tests/"
        }
    },
```